# Migrating Android app from OpenID 2.0 to Google+ Sign-In

Tags: android, google-plus, google-oauth, google-openid

I have both a web app and an Android app that currently offer a Google OpenID 2.0 login option. I am in the process of migrating them to Google+ Sign In, since OpenID 2.0 is deprecated.

For the web app, I am following the migration process described [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#oid2), where I add the `data-openidrealm` attribute to the Sign In button.  As a result, when the login is completed, the `id_token` that I get includes an `openid_id` field, containing the user's OpenID 2.0 identifier. I can use this to determine perfectly whether the user already has an account on my site.

For the Android app, I intend to implement Google+ Sign In using the `SignInButton` widget, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in). However, I don't see any option equivalent to the `data-openidrealm` attribute. How can I get the `openid_id` value so that I can recognize my existing OpenID users when they login?

I know that I could try to match the users by email address, but this will not result in perfect matching, and some users would be unable to access their existing accounts.  I know that I could also implement [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) directly (which would allow passing the `openid.realm` parameter), instead of using the `SignInButton` widget, but this would not be as good of a user experience, and Google discourages it.

So what does Google offer for migrating an Android app from OpenID to Google+?